# what is the role of VBE7.dll?

Tags: excel, vba, vbe

The application is writing data to the excel sheet.
As per our security standards we are blocking macros related to excel and word.
McAfee antivirus is blocking the macros.
The application is in C++ and the data written to excel is done by using MFC and worksheet functions.
when i debugging the code, it is trying to write or execute VBE7.dll and VBE7.dll is blocking by McAfee.
why it is trying to write or execute to VBE7.dll?

Comment: Well, there needs to be any interface between your application and the Excel sheet. Your application cannot *magically* access the Excel file. The dll "knows" how to open/save/access/etc the sheet. So you will need to allow accessing it if you want your application to be able to read/write/etc Excel files.

Comment: You might find this information of some use: https://www.fileinspect.com/fileinfo/vbe7-dll/ I'm not sure this dll does what the other comment says, but it is important for executing "the interop". One thing I know about are the compiler constants VBA7 and Win64  for determining the environment and new data types for 64-bit.